# Best way to insert non-model data using ActiveRecord in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, import, dbi

I'm importing data in a Rails 3 project.  I have 2 slightly different scenarios. I'd like to know if there is a better way.

### Scenario # 1

1. I execute dynamically generated SQL using DBI:ODBC. (DBI since ActiveRecord does not support this database.)
2. I loop through the result set, and insert data into a non-model table using ActiveRecord.

The insert statement is generating using Ruby string formatting like such:

```
while row = result.fetch do
  values = row.to_a     
  insert_sql = "insert into table (column1, column2) values (%s, %s)" % values
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute insert_sql
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?   I'm not too keen on using formatted strings.

### Scenario # 2

Scenario # 2 is similar to # 1...  Instead of getting data from DBI, it's coming from a CSV file.  So in this case the data is text (or strings).  Again, I'm using the insert statement with %s specifiers in it, and inserting into a non-model table using ActiveRecord.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

That depends. If you have a lot of rows to insert and you do not need validation from ActiveRecord, your approach seems right. However, it would work considerably faster if you inserted more than a single record at a time, like this:

```
values = []
values << row while row = result.fetch
values_string = values.map{|v| "({v.join(',')})"}.join(',')
insert_sql = "insert into table (column1, column2) values #{value_string}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute insert_sql
```

If you prefer passing validations, you would need to translate each line of your data sources into an ActiveRecord object. While providing validations and callbacks, this approach is MUCH slower.